# .Net Core API Response convert variables

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, dotnet-httpclient

I am working on calling an API that returns properties in a way that I do not want. So the API response looks like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfds",
  "expires_in": 3200
}
```

I want to return it like:

```
{
  accessToken: "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfds",
  expiresIn: 3200
}
```

Here is the model

```
public class Token
{
  [JsonProperty("access_token")]
  public string accessToken { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
  public int expiresIn { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("token_type")]
  public string tokenType { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller that is calling

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

string tokenString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Token token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(tokenString);

return token;
```

The problem is that is returning the json object but the keys are `access_token` and `expires_in` and not camelcase. Am I doing something wrong?

Now I have other calls that will return `FirstName` so I would want to convert those as well.

Comment: I want my API to return the data like {
  accessToken: "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfds",
  expiresIn: 3200
} instead of {
  "access_token": "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfds",
  "expires_in": 3200
}

Comment: Why not remove the `JsonProperty` attribute?

Comment: @StevenB.because I thought that was what converted it, but maybe that is wrong

Comment: I voted to close. It’s not clear to me what it is you need and what is causing you to have the constraints you have.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your use of the `JsonProperty` in this particular case is causing issues when you serialize. It works fine for reading your incoming JSON, but the same naming will be applied when serializing the same object.

Json.Net has a built-in  `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy` that can be used in a contract resolver to handle snake case serialized property names.

The following test demonstrates the use of that naming strategy to get the desired behavior

```
[TestClass]
public class SnakeCaseNamingTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void SHould_Read_SnakeCase_Naming() {
        var tokenString = @"
        {
          ""access_token"": ""sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfds"",
          ""expires_in"": 3200
        }";

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver {
                NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
            }
        };

        Token token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(tokenString, settings);

        token.Should().NotBeNull();
        token.accessToken.Should().NotBeNull();
        token.expiresIn.Should().Be(3200);
    }

    public class Token {
        public string accessToken { get; set; }
        public int expiresIn { get; set; }
        public string tokenType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Note the removal of the `JsonProperty` attributes from `Token`

```
public class Token {
    public string accessToken { get; set; }
    public int expiresIn { get; set; }
    public string tokenType { get; set; }
}
```

which should allow the class to be serialized by default in the desired format

Comment: Thank you for the suggested answer. However, the issues came from attempting to use same model to get a different format than the mentioned in JsonProperties attribute and without using any additional generalised or local config. It is not from issues in the framework converter. In short it is from incorrect utilisation of the framework. Hope you can correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:** I believe the start should be on the understanding of the problem, If you check your model again you will find it working in two ways. so as when you deserialize from JSON to C# object the convention followed is to bind access_Token to accessToken Property, the serialization will follow the **inverse** of the same way.

**Suggestions:**

- **the ideal** is **(1)** to return the C# object (usually called Data Transfer Model DTO ) itself and **(2)** and then use a generalized custom config that follows the camelCase model.

So you will add this config to your startup [[check this](https://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-mvc-json-output-camelcase-pascalcase/)] (if you want a generalized config):

---

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new PascalCaseJsonProfileFormatter());
        });}
```

---

and then return the object itself and as I said before, preferably to create a separate DTO model and perform the conversion using AutoMapper

- **the less** is to create two models one for deserialization with "access_token" attribute value and the like, and the latter for the serialization with the accessToken attribute value (However I highly recommend the first, because you will gain two things, you will learn how to use the DTO approach i.e. something indispensable in WebApi building, and also save your time from repetitive work especially when you finalize and beautify your work by the use of some automatic converter such as AutoMapper Library .

---

```
 public class Token // use this for Deserialization
    {
        [JsonProperty("access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
        public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("token_type")]
        public string TokenType { get; set; }
    }
    public class TokenDto // use this for Serialization
    {
        [JsonProperty("accessToken")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("expiresIn")]
        public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("tokenType")]
        public string TokenType { get; set; }
    }

// Note that it is highly recommended 
// to respect the C# programming convention 
// in classes and properties naming that follow the pascalCase format
```

---